# Javascript style.display function behaving weird

Tags: javascript, css

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //When user clicks add Household Button ("(+)" BUTTON in center )
const addHouseholdBtn = document.getElementById('addHousehold');
const popup_prompt_menu = document.getElementById('add-household-prompt');
const householdForm = document.getElementById('add-household-form');
const addDriverFormBackBtn = document.getElementById('add-driver-cancel-btn');
const addDriverForm = document.getElementById('add-driver-form-form');
const addDriverFormBorder = document.getElementById('add-driver-form');

addDriverForm.style.display = "none";

popup_prompt_menu.style.display = "none";
householdForm.style.display = "none";



addHouseholdBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the click event from propagating to the document
    popup_prompt_menu.style.display = popup_prompt_menu.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

});

//When User clicks submit button in add-household-prompt

const submitPrompt = document.getElementById('submit-prompt');
const driverCheckBox = document.getElementById('add_driver');
const householdCheckBox = document.getElementById('add_household');
const vehicleCheckBox = document.getElementById('add_vehicle');
const policyCheckBox = document.getElementById('add_policy');
const editHousehold = document.getElementById('edit_household');
const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');



//Submit's the prompt that is displayed when clicking the addhousehold  button
submitPrompt.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (driverCheckBox.checked && householdCheckBox.checked && vehicleCheckBox.checked && policyCheckBox.checked) {
        errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
        popup_prompt_menu.style.display = "none";
        householdForm.style.display = 'block'; // Show the form when all checkboxes are checked

    } else if (!editHousehold.checked) {
        errorMessage.innerText = "Error: Each entry must have driver, household, vehicle and a policy! ";
        errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
        errorMessage.style.color = 'red';

    } else if (editHousehold.checked) {
        errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
        popup_prompt_menu.style.display = "none";
        householdForm.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the form if only editHousehold is checked
    }
});

//Returns back to the prompt from the add household form
const backToPrompt = document.getElementById('back-to-prompt');

backToPrompt.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    householdForm.style.display = "none";
    popup_prompt_menu.style.display = "block";
})

// For back button when prompt is activated

const backToMain = document.getElementById('back-to-main');
backToMain.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    householdForm.style.display = "none";
    popup_prompt_menu.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: roboto;
}

date-wrapper input[type="date"] {
    /* Optional: Reset default input styles */
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;

    /* Optional: Add any additional styling */
    /* Add padding, border, etc. */
}

.household-info {
    text-align: center;
}


.customer-card {
    padding: 50px;
}

.form-wrapper {
    display: flex;

    padding: 20px;
}

.first-half-customers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.second-half-customers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-container {


    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);




}

.date-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.left-labels {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;



}

input {
    margin-top: 4.5px;


}

p {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

label {

    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 1.2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.control {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#next {
    margin-top: 150px;
}

#add-household-prompt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;

}

.pop-up-menu-border {
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 15px;



}

#submit-prompt {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #13AA52;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#submit-prompt:hover {

    background-color: #40aa6c;


}

.add-household-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 47%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.add-household-form-border {
    padding: 40px;

}

.add-household-form-inputs {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 17px;

}

#submit-form-btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #13AA52;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 17px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


#back-to-prompt {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);


}

#back-to-main {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.householdControl-container {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

.add-driver-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;


}

.add-driver-form-border {

    padding: 20px;

}

.section-d {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.add-driver-form-labels,
.add-driver-inputs {
    display: inline-block;
}

#add-driver-submit-btn {
    background-color: #13AA52;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: white;
}

#add-driver-cancel-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/center.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />

  <script src="javascripts/slider-function.js" defer></script>
</head>

<div class="main-container">

  <div class="household-info">
    <h1> Household Information</h1>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <div class = 'first-half-customers'>
      <% selectedHouseholdCustomers.slice(0, 5).forEach(customer => { %>
        <%- include('customer-card', { customer: customer }) %>
      <% }); %>
    </div>

      <div class ='second-half-customers'>
      <% selectedHouseholdCustomers.slice(5, 10).forEach(customer => { %>
        <%- include('customer-card', { customer: customer }) %>
      <% }); %>
    </div>

     
   


      <div class="control">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="addHousehold">add_circle</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="next">arrow_forward_ios</span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id ="previous">arrow_back_ios</span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
 
</div>








 <div class = "householdControl-container">  <%- include ('householdControl', { SelectedHouseholdData: SelectedHouseholdData }) -%></div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const firstHalfCustomers = document.querySelector('.first-half-customers');
  const secondHalfCustomers = document.querySelector('.second-half-customers');

  // Hide the second half of customers initially
  secondHalfCustomers.style.display = 'none';
  

  const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
  const previousButton = document.getElementById('previous');

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstHalfCustomers.style.display = 'none';
    secondHalfCustomers.style.display = 'flex';
    secondHalfCustomers.style.justifyContent = 'space-between';
    
  });

  previousButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstHalfCustomers.style.display = 'flex';
    firstHalfCustomers.style.justifyContent = 'space-between';
    secondHalfCustomers.style.display = 'none';
    
  });
});

  
</script>

<div class = "add-driver-form">
  <div class = "add-driver-form-border">
  <form action = "/add-driver" method = "post" id = "add-driver-form-form"> 
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "full_name" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Driver Full Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="full_name" name="name" class="add-driver-form-inputs">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "dob" class = "add-driver-form-labels"> Driver DOB: </label>
      <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" class="add-driver-form-inputs">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "relation" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Driver Realation: </label>
      <select id="relation" name="relation">
        <option value="self">self</option>
        <option value="spouse">spouse</option>
        <option value="child">child</option>
        <option value="parent">parent</option>
        <option value="sibling">sibling</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "year" class = "add-driver-form-labels"> Vehicle Year: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "year" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "year">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "make" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle Make: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "make" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "make">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "model" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle Model: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "model" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "model">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "vin" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle VIN: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "vin" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "vin">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "policyNumber" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Policy number: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "policyNumber" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "policyNumber">
    </div>
    <button type ="submit" id ="add-driver-submit-btn">Submit </button>
    <button type ="button" id ="add-driver-cancel-btn" >Back </button>
    
    
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>


<!-- Add Household Prompt menu-->
<div class="pop-up-menu" id="add-household-prompt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="pop-up-menu-border" id="add-household-prompt-border">
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="add_driver" name="addDriver" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_driver" class="labels">Create Driver</label>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="add_household" name="addHousehold" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_household" class="labels">Create Household</label>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="add_vehicle" name="addVehicle" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_vehicle" class="labels">Create Vehicle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="add_policy" name="addPolicy" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_policy" class="labels">Create Policy</label>
    </div>
 
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="add_driver" name="add_driver" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_driver" class="labels">Add Driver </label>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up-menu-section">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remove_driver" name="remove_driver" class="checkboxs">
      <label for="add_driver" class="labels">Remove Driver</label>
    </div>
    <buttton type="submit" id="submit-prompt">Submit</buttton>
    <button id="back-to-main">Back </button>
    <p id="error-message">
      <p>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Add Household Form-->
<div class="add-household-form" id="add-household-form">
  <div class="add-household-form-border">

    <h1> New Household</h1>
    <form action="/add_household" method="post">
      <div class="section">
        <label for="upload_picture" class="add-household-form-labels">Upload Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" id="upload_picture" name="upload_picture" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="full_name" class="add-household-form-labels">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="date_of_birth" class="add-household-form-labels">Date Of Birth:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="relation" class="add-household-form-labels">Full Name: </label>
        <select id="relation" name="relation" class="add-household-form-inputs">
          <option value="self">Self</option>
          <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="child">Child</option>
          <option value="parent">Parent</option>
          <option value="sibling">Sibling</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="year" class="add-household-form-labels">Year:</label>
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="make" class="add-household-form-labels">Make:</label>
        <input type="text" id="make" name="make" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="model" class="add-household-form-labels">Model:</label>
        <input type="text" id="model" name="model" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="vin" class="add-household-form-labels">VIN#: </label>
        <input type="text" id="vin" name="vin" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="cell_phone" class="add-household-form-labels">Cell Phone: </label>
        <input type="text" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="address" class="add-household-form-labels">Address: </label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="work_phone" class="add-household-form-labels">Work Phone: </label>
        <input type="text" id="work_phone" name="work_phone" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="city" class="add-household-form-labels">City: </label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="zip_code" class="add-household-form-labels">Zip Code: </label>
        <input type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label for="policy_number" class="add-household-form-labels">Policy Number: </label>
        <input type="text" id="policy_number" name="policy_number" class="add-household-form-inputs">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit-form-btn"> Add Household Member </button>

    </form>
    <button id="back-to-prompt">Back </button>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Edit Household Form -->

<div class = "add-driver-form">
  <div class = "add-driver-form-border">
  <form action = "/add-driver" method = "post" id = "add-driver-form-form"> 
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "full_name" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Driver Full Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="full_name" name="name" class="add-driver-form-inputs">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "dob" class = "add-driver-form-labels"> Driver DOB: </label>
      <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" class="add-driver-form-inputs">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "relation" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Driver Realation: </label>
      <select id="relation" name="relation">
        <option value="self">self</option>
        <option value="spouse">spouse</option>
        <option value="child">child</option>
        <option value="parent">parent</option>
        <option value="sibling">sibling</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "year" class = "add-driver-form-labels"> Vehicle Year: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "year" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "year">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "make" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle Make: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "make" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "make">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "model" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle Model: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "model" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "model">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "vin" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Vehicle VIN: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "vin" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "vin">
    </div>
    <div class = "section-d">
      <label for = "policyNumber" class = "add-driver-form-labels">Policy number: </label>
     <input type = "text" id = "policyNumber" class = "add-driver-form-inputs" name = "policyNumber">
    </div>
    <button type ="submit" id ="add-driver-submit-btn">Submit </button>
    <button type ="button" id ="add-driver-cancel-btn" >Back </button>
    
    
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason driver form still displays the menu over everything and when I try to change it a box of the border appears in the middle. I don't understand why it is working like that I have two previous pop ups that work perfectly except for this one. I tried to affect the visibility as well to no avail.

Comment: Your code snippet does not work; it gets a syntax error. If you're going to make a snippet, it should work; otherwise you're wasting people's time.

Comment: Also, if you want to toggle visibility, don't use `style.display`, create a CSS `.hidden { display: none !important; }` rule, and on the JS side, add/remove/toggle that class using the `.classList` property, not the `.style` property.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you can use [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute for that instead of a class

Comment: @Konrad also true, depends on whether you want to be able to control what "hidden" means. If you just need "remove it from the DOM", the hidden attribute is quite useful.